# How to delete conditional formats for a cell or range using EPPlus

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, epplus

Is there a way to remove Conditional Formatting from a cell or range with EPPlus?  I have tried Clear, Reset, delete rows, insert rows, copy a cell without formatting, but nothing works.  There are ways to remove all the conditional formatting from the sheet (worksheet.RemoveAll or RemoveAt) but not from a cell or range that I have been able to find anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found a way to inspect, change or delete a conditional format of a cell or range looking at the openxml specs.  The conditional format is stored in the worksheet, with the range under the attribute sqref.  So you can edit that range or add a new.

For example:

```
DIM p As New ExcelPackage(New FileInfo(ExlReportPath), True)
Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets(ExlSheetName)
```

'--Find Node "worksheet" (1 in my case) , Find all Child Nodes "conditionalFormatting" (5 to 11 in my test)

```
Print.Debug(ws.WorksheetXml.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(5).Name)
```

'--You get: conditionalFormatting

'--Now you can inspect the range:

```
Print.Debug(ws.WorksheetXml.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(5).Attributes("sqref").Value)
```

'--Will give you the cell address that this formatting applies to example: "D11:D15"
'--you can change delete or add new range if you want, below I add F11:F15

```
ws.WorksheetXml.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(5).Attributes("sqref").Value="D11:D15 F11:F15"
```

'--You can inspect the rule itself in the InnerXml also...

If you need more details of the markup, google  Wouter van Vugt, "Open XML The markup explained".  I found it useful and the full document was online (free).

If you find an easier way please post it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `Address` property of each rule to a new `ExcelAddress` object with an address that omits the cell or sub-range in question, e.g. ---

```
var cfRules = worksheet.ConditionalFormatting;
var cfToModify = cfRules.Where(cf => ofInterest(cf.Address));
foreach (var cf in cfToModify)
{
    // Determine a new address for the rule so that it no longer
    // affects the cell or sub-range you're interested in.
    var newRangeAddress = "something else"; // (Just some filler, won't work...)
    cf.Address = new ExcelAddress(newRangeAddress);
}
```

--- with `ofInterest` defined however you want, e.g.:

```
static bool ofInterest(ExcelAddress addr)
{
    var result = false; // Determine as you see fit.
    return result;
}
```

(Note that the `ExcelAddress.Address` property is read-only, so you have to set the rule's `Address` property to a new `ExcelAddress` object.)